# What is the correct syntax to use LINQ SUM in UnityScript

Tags: linq, unity-game-engine, sum, unityscript

Hello I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for getting the sum from a class list using LINQ in unityscript

```
var totalCount: int;

class munsters {
 var beast: String;
 var min: int = 1;
 var max: int =1;
}

var wilds: List.<munsters>;

//this gives me the error -- 
//InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in OppSpawnTester:OnDrawGizmos (): IL_0007: ldarg.1   
totalCount = wilds.Sum(function(a) a.max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
totalCount = wilds.Select(function(a : munsters) a.max).ToList().Sum();
```

For anyone else still holding on the unityscript :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: `For anyone else still holding on the unityscript` .. why would you though? ^^ This has been deprecated long ago ^^